# Can't resolve symbol "context" on simple program

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a simple hello world program to get my started on Android app development, but I keep getting an error on the TextView line with context on it with "Cannot resolve symbol "Context"

```
package com.example.bryce.firstapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Context context=this;
    TextView TV=new TextView(context: this);
    TV.setText("Hello World");
    setContentView(TV);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Comment: Javascript or Java :-)

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
TextView TV=new TextView(context: this);
```

with:

```
TextView TV=new TextView(this);
```

Also note that the code that you have in `onResume()` normally goes in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may put your code inside `onCreate` instead of `onResume`

anyway, 
just replace

```
TextView TV=new TextView(context: this);
```

with

```
TextView TV=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
```

so you can use your activity to declare the TextView

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
TextView TV=new TextView(context: this);
```

with this

```
TextView TV=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `TextView TV=new TextView(context:this)` line to :

```
TextView TV=new TextView(this);
```

**or**

```
TextView TV=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
```

**or**

```
Context context=this;
TextView TV=new TextView(context);
```

**Another way** is use this code in your activity class:

```
TextView TV=new TextView(getBaseContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

The context isn't necessary. You can display the text you want with this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textView.setText("Hello World");
}
```

Just make sure your TextView has the an id like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```